# Nginx worker process exited

Tags: nginx, safari, dump

I'm getting the following error message from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2014/07/17 08:36:21 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8207 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2014/07/17 08:36:21 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8210 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2014/07/17 08:36:22 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8208 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2014/07/17 08:36:26 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8209 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2014/07/17 08:36:26 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8232 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2014/07/17 08:36:26 [alert] 8206#0: worker process 8236 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
```

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` shows the redirect to `https` which happens if you visit the `http` address:

```
[17/Jul/2014:09:22:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.76.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.1.4 Safari/537.76.4"
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? It is on Ubuntu 12.04 and a standard `apt-get install nginx`.

This is the config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             domain.com;
    ssl_certificate         /ssl/path.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /ssl/path.key;
    error_page              404             /404.html;
    error_page              500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location                = 50x.html {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location                / {
        root    /project/path/root;
    }
    access_log              /project/path/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log               /project/path/logs/nginx-error.log;
    client_max_body_size    20m;
}
```

I only get this error when I view the site using Safari, it happens on multiple machines not just mine and it's the same error displayed on each Safari.

[image]

Comment: I had almost the same issue. Then I googled this article and it helped me.
https://futurestud.io/blog/nginx-solve-reponse-status-0-worker-process-exited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related to the ssl session cache issue that is described in this ticket for nginx, http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/235.

Comment: lol "400 Bad Request The SSL certificate error"

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to use the same session cache for all server blocks, e.g. to configure it on the http{} level.